# managed metadata service database information

Tags: managed-metadata

I have some issue here regarding the metadata service database.  Can anyone tell me where or in which table the information of  all the metadata database is stored in the SQL Server 2008??  I know that each metadata service creates a database with the same name but I could not find where or in which table all the information of the metadata databases gets stored.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The metadata is stored in a separate database, you're correct. Term labels can be found in the table ECMTerm, termsets can be found in table ECMTermSet and so on.

Why are you interested? Please don't change anything, because that will brings the farm in an unsupported state.

Comment: As Anita says, the schema on the SP DBs (excluding the Usage DB) should not be changed. Why? because later when you update your SP farm it will break. The proper method to retrieve the metadata information is within the SP or if creating a custom solution and you want to utilize the taxonomy use SP object models.